# como passar a variável MARCA que recebe um Array por URL em Javascript para outra página? oque estou fazendo de errado?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

```
function escolheControle(c) {   
controle = c;
marca =todasAsmarcas[controle];
window.location="marcaWebkit.htm";
console.log(controle+' controle-----');
console.log(todasAsmarcas+' todasAsmarcas-----');

}

var marca; 
var todasAsmarcas = new Array(4);
    todasAsmarcas[0] = new Array("Samsung", "LG", "Sony", "SempToshiba", "Panasonic", "AOC", "CCE", "Philips", "Sharp", "Toshiba", "Gradiente", "Philco", "Buster", "Semp", "Hitachi", "Sanyo", "Blue Sky", "Mitsubishi", "Aiko", "Cineral", "JVC", "Zenith");
    todasAsmarcas[1] = new Array("Samsung", "LG", "Sony", "SempToshiba", "Panasonic", "AOC", "CCE", "Philips", "Sharp", "Toshiba", "Gradiente", "Philco", "Buster", "Hitachi", "Sanyo", "Blue Sky", "Mitsubishi", "Aiko", "Cineral", "JVC", "Zenith");
    todasAsmarcas[2] = new Array("Samsung", "LG", "Sony", "SempToshiba", "Panasonic", "AOC", "CCE", "Philips", "Sharp", "Toshiba", "Gradiente", "Philco", "Buster", "Hitachi", "Sanyo", "Blue Sky", "Mitsubishi", "Aiko", "Cineral", "JVC", "Zenith");
    todasAsmarcas[3] = new Array("Samsung", "LG", "Sony", "SempToshiba", "Panasonic", "AOC", "CCE", "Philips", "Sharp", "Toshiba", "Gradiente", "Philco", "Buster", "Semp", "Hitachi", "Sanyo", "Blue Sky", "Mitsubishi", "Aiko", "Cineral", "JVC", "Zenith");


function onRcu(e) {     
switch (e.keyName) {                
       case iAppLib.keys.OK:
           switch(pagina){
            case "menuWebkit":
                escolheControle(contMenu);
                window.location="marcaWebkit.htm?contMenu=0  marca=todasAsmarcas[controle] controle=c index=0";                 
                console.log("OKAY");
                //top.main.escolheControle(contMenu);
                break;
           }
            break;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, 
para montar o url com varios parametros vc precisa incluir o simbolo & ao invés dos espaços.
Além de que, voce também não pode passar uma variavel dentro de uma string como esta fazendo no caso de "marca=todasAsmarcas[controle]".

Crie uma variael URL e adicione mais ou menos assim:

```js
var url = "marcaWebkit.htm?contMenu="+contMenu+"&marca="+todasAsmarcas[controle]+"&controle="+c+"&index="+index;
```

E aí no case vc chama assim:

```js
window.location=url;
```

Comment: Muito obrigada por me ensinar Marcelo, agora ele esta printandoo nome das marcas corretamente, porém ele esta printando letra por letra, eu quero printar o Samsung inteiro por exemplo e quando apertar para a direita ir para o LG, mas ele esta printando letra por letra do Samsung e depois vai para o LGe assim sucessivamente.....

Comment: Adicionei a função que esta printando esse array
Será que é devido ao document.querySelector ? ele pega um por um? vou pesquisar!

Comment: function initial(x) { 
  //document.getElementById("estiloId1")+todasAsmarcas[index];
  //var num = index + 1;
  document.querySelector("[name='marca']").value = marca[index]; 
  console.log(marca[index]+"marca que deve ser printada dentro do input---------");
  //console.log(num+"  numero do meu index que estou chamando de outra pagina--------");
}